# Waiting times for php page

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am debugging performance issue for my ajax application.

Firefox developer tools shows around 3 seconds as Waiting time.

If i try to measure php script by getrusage() 'ru_utime.tv_sec' and 'ru_utime.tv_usec', i get randomly 0.2 to 9 seconds at script beginning and difference between script beginning and end is around 0.07 seconds.

So how do i interpret these results?
Does it mean that php code itself run for 0.07 seconds and remaining time is for sql queries etc? (i really have many complicated queries in my script)

Or does it mean that apache or php interpreter do something before executing actual php code?

Or may it be not server fault, but ajax an jquery?

debian. php version is 5.4, apache - 2.2, jquery 1.11.

Upd:
Sorry, i forgot to mention important information - i run multiple ajax requests from page. if i run one request separatelly, Waiting time is 0,6 second.

Comment: Is the TTFB times consistent?

Comment: Yes, i think TTFB are consistent. "+2.24 Request start time since the beginning" for each request.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using localhost? If so chances are it will be slower. Upgrade to PHP 7 if you can it has massive speed improvements. Apache, switch out for nginx if you want even better performance. Apache is like a 4 by 4, contains everything you need, nginx is more like a Ferrari, not much there but it does what you need it to.

Though it won't matter, jQuery is now on version 3, you are running an old version.

Comment: Debian distribution and my colleague who is administering server are little conservative. I doubt i will get newest php (or mysql 5.6.3+ which will dramatically improve my query performance) any time soon :(

Comment: php 5.4 is a potential security risk, it is end of life and has been for over a year now. If he is conservative get a document together advising on the risks of staying on PHP 5.4 and the benefits of upgrading, iirc 7 uses less resources than 5.x as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, getrusage() measures only time of PHP code execution itself.
If i want to measure query streams etc, i need to measure real time.

```
$GLOBALS["mymicrotime"] = microtime(true);
//code here
print_r(microtime(true) - $GLOBALS["mymicrotime"]);
```

Parallel scripts run 3 seconds instead of 0.6 seconds, because of some kind of locking in Interbase/Firebird queries.